# Start stopped EC2 instance in AWS via CloudFormation

Tags: aws-cloudformation

I have to start EC2 instances which are already stopped in my AWS account. I'm trying to build a CloudFormation script to do it.

1. Is this possible via CloudFormation without using any Lambda functions?
2. If not, what are the alternatives?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming those instances were created manually (*i.e.* not via CloudFormation).

1. None that I'm aware of.
2. Using [Lambda-backed custom resources](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-custom-resources.html) would be your best bet in my opinion, in case you really want to do it via CloudFormation. If you're open to accomplishing the same task without CloudFormation, it might be easier to do it using the AWS CLI.

Comment: Thanks Aditya,
Instance was created via CF , i have attached few device and want start instance from in same CF. If its not possible in CF than i will look in to lambda function.